# How to retrieve data from the same form and display in another form using asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc 4.

I have one Business Card form (in this form two options are submit-when i will click then it will  store data into the database,preview-will display one table which will display the preview of the business card) ,I have to fill the form ,after filling the form ,before submitting the form if I want to see the how my business card will be then only if I will click on preview button then it should display the a preview window which will display how my business card will be ?

Can any one give me some suggestion that how I can retrieve the value from the same form and display in another table.As I have not stored the data into the database ,so only I have to fetch the data from the same form only ?

I am using asp.net mvc4 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it in JavaScript/JQuery by traversing form's inputs and inserting this data into your preview table

```
$('#formId').find('input').each(function(){
   var input = $(this); 
   input.val(); //-- returns you a value from the input
   input.attr('name'); // - returns you a name of the input
   // retrieved info could be inserted into a table/template/other form 
})
```

> As I have not stored the data into the database ,so only I have to fetch the data from the same form only ?

If you didn't store your data anywhere (server / local storage / cookies) than yes you have to fetch it from your form.

Comment: shall i create a temporary table for inserting the data into temporarypreview table ?or can i do one thing when i will click on preview the data will store into the temporarypreview table and again i will retrieve the data from the same ?Is it a good way for solving this problem ?or any other way ?

Comment: Without storing the data somewhere you don't have many options...
I think you should create a template for preview and when user clicks on preview button simply fill it with data from your form and display it in some modal dialog. When user closes the dialog the original data is still in the form and ready to be submitter/edited. I don't think it is a bad way solving your issue but the decision is yours...

Comment: will you tell me how to use dialog box asp.net mvc 4

Comment: It is not related specifically to asp.net MVC but to client side development (javascript/html/css) you can check for example http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals